# Does this text flow smoothly (description of suicidal thoughts)?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing, description, narrative

> So how did this animal suicide thing start? Ironically, it began with
>   my own death wish. But why? I had perfect health, friends and family
>   who cared about me, plus I had just been admitted into college.
>
> Well, basically, I stopped finding meaning in things. Not in a
>   spiritual or philosophical way, though; things simply ceased to make
>   sense. I'd be riding the train or crossing the street and ask myself:
>   What's the meaning of all this? You wake up, go to work, eat, poop,
>   crawl back to bed—then die. Yes, some will remember you, but those
>   people will die, too. And even if you make yourself a place in
>   history, all traces of that will disappear once we blow ourselves up
>   with nuclear weapons, or  once the universe undergoes a cosmic
>   explosion.
>
> **I concluded the most logical thing to do was to end with my life.**
>
> **My mind made up, I holed up in my apartment one night to think of the
>   most suitable method.** Jumping from a building wasn't an option; I was
>   afraid of heights. Hanging—I was terrible at tying knots. Even my
>   shoe's, which untangled every 5 minutes. After giving it a lot of
>   though, I decided on pills. Easy: grab a bunch, pop them into your
>   mouth, then wash them down with water.

I'm especially concerned about the transition between monologue and action/scene (is that how they're called?), which I marked with **bold.**

Let me know if you want me to include more paragraphs.

Comment: I know this is super late and random, but if this person wants to die, why would a fear of heights justify not jumping off a building? People are afraid of heights because of the possibility of death and falling, after all, right? So if that's already the intention, there is nothing to be afraid of. 
I think the tradition works by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition seems fairly smooth to me, probably because the action doesn't feel like action: It feels like the continuation of the musings in the earlier paragraphs.

Maybe this is because we're not seeing the setup, but I think the entire excerpt feels rushed. This is someone who's thinking through reasons why life just doesn't make sense, but I'm not buying any of it: It seems detached, almost philosophical.

I think that easing us into this more gradually and giving the reader some anchor points - something like motivations or action touchpoints - would help.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes, it's supposed to sound detached and a bit silly. The story is about a girl who's researching about drowning ducks, jumping cows, hanging chihuahuas after all.